# I have instance of some Event and ticket-instances to that event how can i add all created ticket-instances to event instance list

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have Event and Ticket class (types of ticket like Student, Late, Advanced dont matter in this problem i think, they just change price of the ticket.

So i want instance of Event type to append all instances of Ticket type to its tickets-list

```
class Event:

def __init__(self, event_date=datetime.today().date()):
    self.event_date = event_date
    self.today = datetime.today().date()
    self.tickets = []

def buy_ticket(self, student=False):
    if student and (self.event_date - self.today).days >= 10:
        return StudentTicket()
    elif (self.event_date - self.today).days < 10:
        return LateTicket()
    elif (self.event_date - self.today).days >= 60:
        return AdvancedTicket()
    else:
        return Ticket()

class Ticket:
def __init__(self):
    self.price = 100
    self.number = uuid.uuid4()

def __str__(self):
    return f'Number: {self.number}\nType: {self.__class__.__name__}\nPrice: {self.price}\n'
```

So for example i do this:

```
ev = Event(datetime(2020, 11, 28).date())

t1 = ev.buy_ticket()
t2 = ev.buy_ticket()

print(t1) 'Number: cadd3d01-245d-46ab-85e2-f044ff92ba9f
           Type: Ticket
           Price: 100'
print(t2) 'Number: 2d8a6738-4c0e-41cd-9b71-565bf90b6bc3
           Type: Ticket
           Price: 100'

print(ev.tickets)# Should print sth like this: 
               '[<__main__.Ticket object at 0x10CD3820>, <__main__.Ticket object at 0x10CD37C0>]'
for i in ev.tickets:
    print(i)# Should print:
            'Number: cadd3d01-245d-46ab-85e2-f044ff92ba9f
             Type: Ticket
             Price: 100'

            'Number: 2d8a6738-4c0e-41cd-9b71-565bf90b6bc3
             Type: Ticket
             Price: 100'
```

Every ticket-instance that I create from ev(t1, t2) has to be added to the ev.tickets. Cant find any information how to implement it.

Comment: in ev.buy_ticket() you do a `self.tickets.append(whatever you return in buy_ticket())` and you init `self.tickets` on `Event.__init__(...)` ?

Comment: please fix your `IndentationError`s

Answer (score 1):

You should append `Ticket` while creating them in `Event.buy_ticket`.

```py
class Event:

    def __init__(self, event_date=datetime.today().date()):
        self.event_date = event_date
        self.today = datetime.today().date()
        self.tickets = []

    def buy_ticket(self, student=False):
        ticket = None
        if student and (self.event_date - self.today).days >= 10:
            ticket = StudentTicket()
        elif (self.event_date - self.today).days < 10:
            ticket = LateTicket()
        elif (self.event_date - self.today).days >= 60:
            ticket = AdvancedTicket()
        else:
            ticket = Ticket()
        self.tickets.add(ticket) # add created ticked to your Event instance
        return ticket
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the `append` method on your list to add the newly-created ticked to the end of your tickes list before you return it. Something like this:

```
def buy_ticket(self, student=False):
    if student and (self.event_date - self.today).days >= 10:
        t = StudentTicket()
    elif (self.event_date - self.today).days < 10:
        t = LateTicket()
    elif (self.event_date - self.today).days >= 60:
        t = AdvancedTicket()
    else:
        t = Ticket()

    self.tickets.append(t)
    return t
```

Your problem was that all you were doing was creating the ticket, you never actually interacted with your ticket list.